# I am having troubles converting string into date (error)

Tags: powerbi

I am having troubles converting this fields into date.[image]
[image]
Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other dates are wrong, too:

11/7/2022 should be 2022-11-07, not 2022-07-11,

because

1/16/2023 must be a US date format MM/DD/YYYY
(there is no 16th month)

You can convert the string in Power BI "Using Locale ..." and then specifying English/US.

[image]

[image]